# Needed advice on how to deploy a HTML5 mobile app in the android and iphone market

Tags: android, iphone, mobile-application

I have made an HTML5 mobile app which I want to release both in the android and the iphone app market. So whats the easiest way I can do that. I had originally thought of making a small webview, which will be native code, both for the android and the iphone, which will serve as an entry point to the HTML5 app, but I am not sure if this will pass verification, is this correct? and if so do you have any other suggestions how I can solve the problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i mean, whenever an app needs to be put in the market place for android or iphone, it needs to be verified, I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/) to embed javascript and html in a native app

Comment: Thanks, I will look into this. But I had 2 questions. Firstly, wont that webview idea work and secondly, for phonegap, it is all just JS and HTML5, or do I need to learn a new language or something. The reason I am asking this question is, i just wanted to know how much of my code would i need to change. Does PhoneGap have its own js libraries or something?

Comment: yes the webview is a great idea, but you will still need to learn Java and objective-C to implement them. By using phonegap you just click a few times inside a wizard and replace phonegap js/html with you own.  

Second: yes phonegap has it own libs but I just delete them when using the framework and I replace them by my own js and html.

Comment: oh, thanks, but I know how to make a native android app, its just iphone app, which I dont know how to make, but I think I can manage to make a simple webview on the iphone, thanks!!!